# How do I use the Ring of Hircine and become a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the ring but I don't know how to use it. I made it so that it is not cursed, and i think that was a mistake. If possible, how do I transform using the ring?

If it isn't, how do I drink a werewolf's blood myself?

Comment: Have you looked under "Powers" in your magic menu, after equipping the ring?

Answer (score 4):

The Ring of Hircine does not automatically make you a werewolf: it just grants you the ability to transform one additional time per day<sup>1</sup>, but only if you *already* have lycanthropy.

The only way to contract lycanthropy is to seek out the Companions.

> Specifically, you need to complete the blood ritual found in *The Silver Hand* quest.

You can find the Companions hanging out at Jorrvaskr in Whiterun. The quest chain begins with the quest, *Take Up Arms*.

Once you have lycanthropy, you can transform by activating *Beast Form* under the *Powers* menu.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: As [Raven Dreamer mentions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35494/how-do-i-use-the-ring-of-hircine-and-become-a-werewolf#comment57977_40120), this can be reset by re-quipping the ring, effectively granting you unlimited transformations a day.

Comment: Is that the only way that you know of Mark Trapp?

Comment: @Coolerz Completing the blood ritual is the only way to contract lycanthropy: it's something like a guild "perk" of the Companions.

Comment: I had saved Sinding and then killed him, hoping he would bite me and I would become infected. But now that I know, killing him wasn't a complete waste of time.

Comment: That's not right at all. When you are a werewolf you can normally transform once a day. The ring is supposed to make it so you can transform into a werewolf without being turned first off and second at any time, for as many times, though it sounds by him that it worked because he can transform once a day.

Comment: Why would the ring give you the ability to transform only if you are already a werewolf? You already have the ability to transform once a day when you have lycanthropy.

Comment: @Jupotter One additional time per day (so, two total). Fixed.

Comment: you know that you can become a werewolf without actually doing the blood ritual?

Comment: @disponser You can't: contracting lycanthropy outside of the Companions quest line is an urban legend that has been refuted numerous times.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed an answer suggesting the ring only allows you a single additional transformation per day. This is untrue. The ring and it's power give you unlimited transformations, provided the ring is equipped. To use the power of the ring, simply use the magicka menu, scroll down to powers, and activate the power of Hircine's ring.

Comment: Slight addenda - the ring gives one additional transformation per day per time equipped - reequipping the ring resets the cooldown. And since you automatically unequip all items when you get your beast form on...