# How Do I Drink a Werewolf's Blood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had heard that you can do anything multiple ways on ***Skyrim***. I didn't want to join the companions to become a werewolf. I had also heard that you can drink a werewolf's blood to become one. What are the differents ways of becoming a wearwolf ?

Comment: Edited the question so the question is about the different ways of becoming a wearwolf (which was in my opinion OP question). The linked duplicate don't answer this question

Comment: @WizLiz other ways of becoming a werewolf are still ways of becoming a werewolf, this is a dupe.

Comment: @kotekzot well the accepted answer does not contain detail about the Ring thing so I assumled it was different things. I'm not familiar with the game but mb then the question needs an update

Answer (score 4):

You drink the Companions' (who are werewolves) blood to become a werewolf. To the best of my knowledge, there is no other way to drink a werewolf's blood than by becoming a companion.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to become a lycanthrope [except through completing the blood ritual in the Companions quest, *The Silver Hand*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35494/how-do-i-use-the-ring-of-hircine-and-become-a-werewolf/35500#35500). That is where you drink the werewolf blood.

Comment: Not true. You can get the Ring of Hircine but if you do, its true ability of letting become a werewolf at any time goes away so the best way is to do the companions guild. It's a good guild. You don't kill any quest people and it's the only way to power up the werewolf.

Comment: Doesn't the Ring of Hircine only transform you at random if you've already acquired the ability to transform?

Comment: The ring does make you transform randomly, unless you help the werewolf that your supposed to kill for hiricine. He says you turned the hunt inside out, because you kill the hunters instead, which after you get the ring you can go back in the cave, then kill the werewolf and get saviors hide too.

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways to become a werewolf. One is to complete the companion quest line where they will make you drink the werewolf blood if you want. The second is to be attacked by a werewolf which cause you to catch the disease.

Comment: While being attacked and catching a disease is true of vampires, you won't contract lycanthropy through being attacked by a werewolf.