# Unlimited Werewolf Transformation

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use the Ring of Hircine and become a werewolf?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35494/how-do-i-use-the-ring-of-hircine-and-become-a-werewolf)

I am currently a werewolf and have heard of a ring that allows unlimited transformations. Is there such a thing? And if it does exist, where do I find it?

Comment: pretty sure this has been asked before...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a thing. It's a Daedric artefact called the [Ring of Hircine](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ring_of_Hircine), which is obtained through a quest (hidden for the spoiler-averse):

> The quest is called [Ill Met By Moonlight](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ill_Met_By_Moonlight), which you can start by talking to Sinding in a jail cell in the Falkreath barracks. You can optionally talk to a man called Mathies in the graveyard outside the Hall of the Dead in Falkreath for more backstory.
>  You will have the option to destroy or restore the ring (by killing or helping Sinding, respectively). For unlimited transformations you will need to help him.